# Node.js Event Loop Order Misunderstanding Between setTimeout() and Promise.resolve() in Versions Prior to v11

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm exploring the intricacies of the Node.js Event Loop, Timers, and process.nextTick() in versions predating v11, such as v10.19.0 - without higher priority of microtask and nexttick. I'm referencing the documentation on [nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick), where it states that the first phase of the event loop is timers. And Promise was executed between each phase of the event loop.

Here's a sample code snippet:

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('promise'));
setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout'));
```

I understand that, according to the documentation, the first phase of the event loop is timers. However, when running the above code, the result should be 'timeout' before 'promise', but it is 'promise' before 'timeout'.
Result with nodejs v10.19.0:

```
promise
timeout
```

In contrast, the following code snippet produces the expected result of the timeout occurring before the promise:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout1'));
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('timeout2');
  Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log('promise'));
});
setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout3'));
setTimeout(() => console.log('timeout4'));
```

Result with nodejs v10.19.0:

```
timeout1
timeout2
timeout3
timeout4
promise
```

I'm puzzled about the order of phases in the event loop in 2 examples above.

Comment: perhaps promises back then used `setImmediate` or `process.nextTick` internally - the semantics of those are not as straight forward as you may think - all described in the documentation you linked to though

Comment: But I don't understand the order of phases in event loop.

Comment: https://javascript.info/event-loop - by the way, I believe `v10.19.0` did have microtasks, at least Promises used `microtask` queue - not sure if it was exposed in `queueMicrotask` but the source code does mention a microtask queue in node 10.19

Comment: If Promises used ```microtask``` queue, why in the second example, the callback's promise called after timeout3, timeout4 ?

Comment: Perhaps the microqueue was not implemented the same way 10 major versions ago as it is today? Or I could be wrong and there were no microtask queue in version 10.19 (it was a very quick and dirty search I did) - not sure why you're obsessed with how node used to work though?

Comment: judging from some quick tests, whatever Promises did back then, it's equivalent to using `setImmediate` - which is deprecated, but perhaps that's what Promises used

Comment: These outputs are expected and shouldn't be any different on current versions of Node. *"the first phase of the event loop is timers."*: but surely only *expired* timers. The default for the argument that you omitted is 1 (millisecond), so it wouldn't be expired immediately.